# Why is 'continue' statement ignoring the loop counter increment in 'while' loop, but not in 'for' loop?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, while-loop, continue

Why does it tend to get into an infinite loop if I use `continue` in a `while` loop, but works fine in a `for` loop?
The loop-counter increment `i++` gets ignored in `while` loop if I use it after `continue`, but it works if it is in `for` loop.

If `continue` ignores *subsequent* statements, then why doesn't it ignore the third statement of the `for` loop then, which contains the counter increment `i++`? Isn't the third  statement of `for` loop *subsequent* to `continue` as well and should be ignored, given the third statement of `for` loop is executed *after* the loop body?

```
while(i<10)   //causes infinite loop
{
    ...
    continue
    i++
    ...
}

for(i=0;i<10;i++)  //works fine and exits after 10 iterations
{
    ...
    continue
    ...
}
```

Comment: Look at the output assembly and you'll see that for loops are not expanded how you think.

Comment: Q: What happens if you put `continue` *AFTER* `i++` in your "while" loop?  Q: You understand that the initialization, increment, and condition are all part of the same construct in your "for" loop?  That they're always executed, independent of what happens inside the loop?

Comment: @JesusRamos I haven't progressed yet to that level where assembly would make sense to me!!

Comment: @paulsm4 But doesn't the third statement of `for` loop come after the loop body each time and `continue` is expected to ignore everything that comes after it?Why is it ignoring the `i++` of while then?

Comment: Another contradictory claim--**A continue statement in a for statement causes the first expression of the for statement to be evaluated**---http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/0ceyyskb(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Q: But doesn't the third statement of for loop come after the loop body each time.  A: Yes.  Q: ...continue is expected to ignore everything that comes after it?  A: No :)

Comment: @paulsm4 Please look into the link I gave and the statement I quoted.That is very much confusing.How can the control pass to the first statement of the for loop?That way the counter will be set to original value each time!!That contradicts what I know,and what you are telling me.That **Microsoft** site I mean.

Comment: Thokchom, I suggest you find some better doco than what MS has provided :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo Please confirm it.What is said there about `continue`, that it passes control to first statement of `for`loop, is **wrong** ?I am not sure because Microsoft is supposed to be synonymous with trust.Even my OS is Microsoft product.

Comment: MS synonymous with trust? I decline to comment :-) Whether it's wrong or misunderstood, I'll leave for you to decide. It _does_ pass control back to the first statement of the `for` body but _only_ after executing the post-op stuff first.

Comment: @paxdiablo There it seems to say the condition is checked after the first statement...`A continue statement in a for statement causes the first expression of the for statement to be evaluated. Then the compiler reevaluates the conditional expression and, depending on the result`

Comment: Thokchom, I think that's a typo, the conditional expression is the middle one, so I suspect what they meant was "... causes the _third_ expression of the for statement to be evaluated".

Comment: Why is anybody even looking at vendor documentation for C compilers rather than reading a proper C book or the standard? This is the second time in the past two days that a vendor's bogus documentation had somebody confused (the last time, it was IBM's fault).

Comment: For what it's worth, the MSDN pages for VS2008+ are accurate.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Because `continue` goes back to the start of the loop. With `for`, the post-operation `i++` is an *integral* part of the loop control and is executed before the loop body restarts.

With the `while`, the `i++` is just another statement in the body of the loop (no different to something like `a = b`), skipped if you `continue` before you reach it.

Comment: I'll be dead!!The Microsoft site has another contradictory description.It says `A continue statement in a for statement causes the first expression of the for statement to be evaluated`--http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/0ceyyskb(v=vs.80).aspx Can you explain how come control goes to first statement of `for` loop?

Comment: @Thokchom, given that the link on that page leading to the `for` statement doesn't even describe the third section (the post-op), I'd be relying on something else to learn.

Comment: @Thokchom the description on that page is horribly broken. The link they provide tot he page describing the `for` statement explicitly is accurate. You may want to consider submitting a correction request.

Comment: @NikBougalis Can't believe a Microsoft site can be so unprofessional.

Comment: @Thokchom Relax, mistakes happen. Especially when you have to maintain a website with as much content as MSDN.

Comment: @Thokchom: Yesterday we had a question where it was IBM's documentation for the C compiler on AIX that was similarly bogus. **Don't** rely on vendor documentation. Read the C standard or a reputable book on C.

Answer (score 11):

The reason is because the `continue` statement will short-circuit the statements that follow it in the loop body. Since the way you wrote the `while` loop has the increment statement following the `continue` statement, it gets short-circuited. You can solve this by changing your `while` loop.

A lot of text books claim that:

```
for (i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    /*...*/
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
i = 0;
while (i < N) {
    /*...*/
    ++i;
}
```

But, in reality, it is really like:

```
j = 0;
while ((i = j++) < N) {
    /*...*/
}
```

Or, to be a little more pedantic:

```
i = 0;
if (i < 10) do {
    /*...*/
} while (++i, (i < 10));
```

These are more equivalent, since now if the body of the `while` has a `continue`, the increment still occurs, just like in a `for`. The latter alternative only executes the increment after the iteration has completed, just like `for` (the former executes the increment before the iteration, deferring to save it in `i` until after the iteration).

Comment: @Thokchom: The difference is that the last formulation would allow your `continue` in the `while` loop to continue to increment.

Comment: Oh..that will be handy when one wants the `continue` **not to** ignore the increment.Nice trick! +1

Comment: @Thokchom: Thanks, I updated the answer to make my intention more clear.

Answer (score 3):

Your increment of `i` is after continue, so it never gets executed

```
while(i<10)   //causes infinite loop
{
.........
continue
i++
......
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In any loop, continue moves execution back to the top of the loop, **not executing any other instructions after the continue statement**.

In this case, the for loop's definition is always executed (per standard C), whereas the i++; statement is NOT executed, because it comes AFTER the continue statement.

Answer (score 0):

Because the third part of the for is always executed.

Comment: This answer should be linked  in dictionaries under "tautological".

Answer (score 0):

`continue` statement jumps the control to the end of the statements in current iteration of loop i.e. it skips the execution of the statements in the current iteration and moves to the next iteration of the loop.

With `while` loop, `continue` statement causes control to reach the end of statements (including increment statement), thus causing loop to continue forever.

With `for` loop, `continue` statement jumps the control to end of statement and excutes the increment statement (In `for` loop, increment statement is considered seperate from the statments written within the body of the loop).

Answer (score 0):

for loop holds condition statements and increment, so when the condition is satisfied it goes to execute the statement inside for loop,but if write continue statement than it will again reached to first line of for loop i.e. increment and checking of condition statement, if satisfied than again comes in for execution.
For while loop it just checks the condition statement and if condition satisfied it goes for the execution of statements in the while loop.
so continue will not execute any line after it.and hence your condition satisfied every time and goes for the infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

`continue` bypasses the rest of the block and begins again at the top of the block if the conditional of the loop is met.

The next question is:  "What do I do, then?"
There are two answers I can think of.

*Example:*

```
void foo ()
{
    size_t i = 0;
    do
    {
        /*...*/
        if ( /*...*/ )
        {
            /*...*/
            continue;
        }
        /*...*/
        i++;
    } while ( /* loop conditional */ );
}
```

*Solution #1:* Manually Increment

```
void foo ()
{
    size_t i = 0;
    do
    {
        /*...*/
        if ( /*...*/ )
        {
            /*...*/
            i++;
            continue;
        }
        /*...*/
        i++;
    } while ( /* loop conditional */ );
}
```

*Solution #2:* A uniquely valid application of `goto`*

```
void foo ()
{
    size_t i = 0;
    do
    {
        /*...*/
        if ( /*...*/ )
        {
            /*...*/
            goto foo_next;
        }
        /*...*/
foo_next:
        i++;
    } while ( /* loop conditional */ );
}
```

`goto` is valid in this case because incrementation in two places is technically the same instruction. This solution is especially relevant when the per-iteration-volatile variables are more complex; such as, setting multiple variables or modifying a value with an equation or function.

In the event of a single increment or decrement statement, Solution #1 may prove favorable; however, it should be noted that:  if the code is modified after such an implementation, one must remember to update both instances of the statement (which may be prone to bugs, especially if the modifications take place after an extended period of time**). Therefore, I highly reccomend Solution #2.

*Some consider any and all use of `goto` bad practice. I recommend you decide for yourself, and leave you this: [google for "c goto bad"](https://www.google.com/search?q=c+goto+bad&oq=c+goto+bad&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i64l3.2227j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8)

**A comment reminding of this necessity may suffice, but — if my advice has been followed — the per-iteration-volatile variables in are restricted to a single statement. And I quote:

> There is *never* a reason to comment a single line

-Linus Torvalds (source: http://yarchive.net/comp/linux/coding_style.html)